# What is this vine with cordate, alternate leaves?

Tags: identification, vines

Someone in US gave this plant to my friend who lives in Vietnam, to cure his cancer. It was grown in the US. What is this plant?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this plant is going to cure anyones cancer. |Is it an indoor plant or an outdoor plant?

Comment: Where did the plant come from? Can you take a pic of one individual leaf against a contrasting background?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it's wilting. Can you nurse it back to health? The leaves remind me of a legume, but lots of plants may have bean-like leaves.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [kava, *Piper methysticum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kava), to me, or more likely Betel ([*Piper betle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betel)), due to the part where the leaf meets the leaf-stem. I could be wrong. I searched for cancer-curing plants, and it popped up. It looks like it. Whether it may help with cancer, I can't say, but there's probably a reason for the association, whether or not it's an all-out cure.

A plant an American sends isn't guaranteed to be an American plant, especially in the realm of alternative medicine.

Comment: +1 This does look similar. It's hard to tell, though with the condition the photographed plant is in, and the photo quality.